# É seguro usar filter_input para receber senha de outra página? devo usar algum filter ou sanitizer?

Tags: php, segurança, senhas

Sou novato ainda em programação então não sei quais as formas seguras de tratar uma senha.

Answer (score 1):

A sanitização de entradas é uma prática de segurança não somente para senhas. Um atacante, vai explorar todas as formas de entradas de dados, para saber como quebrar sua aplicação. Inclusive entre páginas ou entre sistemas, quando você faz uma chamada externa.

Seria interessante, você aplicar filtros pré-programados na sua linguagem e/ou aplicar avaliações como expressões regulares, para validar o dado, dentro do formato que você espera. Se o campo é de email, tem um formato próprio. Se o campo é de telefone, tem o formato. Qualquer coisa diferente disso, pode ser um ataque.

Dá trabalho validar?! Dá, mas uma aplicação mais segura tem mais valor. Ninguém gosta de sistemas que não se pode confiar.